# Javascript keyPress on a WinMobile 6.1, IEM 6.8 device doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ie-mobile

I have a Motorola MC70 Scanner with WM 6.1 as OS and IEM 6.8 as browser.
We developed a web application to increase the scan speed in our warehouse.
But it doesn't work the way we want.

I just created a simple test document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Einlagerungen</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<h1>Einlagerungen</h1>
<form method="post" >
    <div class="form-row">
        <label class="label" for="menge">Menge:</label>
        <input id="menge" onKeypress="test()" >
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function test(){
        alert("miau");
    }
</script>
```

And if I do a Input on my Browser, it works well and the alert show up.
But if I do a Input via the Scanner, nothing is happening.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: So you give the input focus and then scan?  Does the input show the output from the scanner or is it still empty?

Comment: Does your scanner support javascript ? at all? `<noscript>Bad news</noscript>` if you see bad news, it means your scanner does not support javascript.

Comment: @Val Windows Mobile supports Javascript.  It's a lite version of IE.

Comment: alternatively, it may be that `onkeypress` should be lower case ? or `... onkeypress="test" ...` not `onkeypress="test()"`

Comment: @Val - `if I do a Input on my Browser, it works well and the alert show up`  Also you need the parenthesis when you assign event handlers inline.

Comment: Why does it say `document.getElementById`?  That line is either incomplete or completely wrong.

Comment: If I scan, the field get filled with the scan code (number, after number). And I have a keyboard on the scanner to put in some stuff manual. The lower case "onkeypress" doesn't work neither ;-/

Comment: @Archer that can be ignored, my bad ;D

Comment: You'll have to manually check for changes then, if no event is being triggered.  That does sound very odd as scanners usually identify as a keyboard (to the OS).  Personally, I'd just put a submit button on the page so it doesn't matter how the input gets populated.

Comment: @Archer That's the thing, the whole reason we do this is to avoid something like this. Because it is like this: the warehouser take a rag, than they scan the scan code, than they have to manual go to the next field, than they scan again, than they have to go the next field, and than they submit it via button. It would be better if they scan and are able to immediately scan the next thing, without doing something manual.

Comment: If there's no event then there's no event.  Use a timer to check the input value and move to the next field when it's the correct format.